# MongoDB: insert on duplicate key update

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How can do this with Mongo in one [atomic] statement:

```
insert mytable set MyUniqueKey = ?, X = ? on duplicate key update Y = ?
```

When this statement is executed for first time it will set X value but after that it will only update Y value.

Only MyUniqueKey is part of unique key and should be looked up for duplicates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I asked this question on mongodb user group, the answer was that it is not possible and this is an open [issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-340).

Comment: This issue has been closed in MongoDB 2.4 and you can now use [`$setOnInsert`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/setOnInsert/).

Answer (score 16):

You are looking for the [upsert option](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-parameter) on the `Update` command. The docs should be enough here.

Comment: would you please give an example. I have already tried many combination of options, but I can't select a field to be set on insert but be excluded on update.

Comment: there is a field I like to be set only on first insert but remain un-touched on updates.

Comment: You have to make `Y` part of the `query` portion of the update instead of part of the `update` portion.

Answer (score 5):

From

> [$setOnInsert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/setOnInsert/)

I would call it "MyCollection" instead of "mytable".
You can do the following:

```
db.mycollection.update(
   { MyUniqueKey: "?" },
   {  
      $set: {"y": "?"},
      $setOnInsert: {
          MyUniqueKey: "?",
           "x": "?",
   },
   { upsert: true }
)
```

Basically the $set runs always, except when document does not exist. Then $setOnInsert will run.