# Is mongodb has the equivalent way of mysql's on duplicate key update?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, insert

Mysql can update the field  with the new value and the exist value when the row  exist like this,

```
insert into table (col1, col2) 
values (value1, value2) 
on duplicate key update 
col1 = col1 + values(col1);
```

Is mongodb has the equivalent way?

I just know the upsert option, which can only set the new value to the exist one.
How to use the new value and exist value at the same time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update a field using its previous value in MongoDB/Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43770216/how-to-update-a-field-using-its-previous-value-in-mongodb-mongoose)

Comment: You can use : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059739/mongodb-insert-on-duplicate-key-update

Comment: @eol Here is not find and update. Here is update when insert. If the row not exist, it will insert it, and if exist, it will update it.

Comment: You're right, nvm :)

Comment: I think you can get that behavior using the `upsert` option.

Comment: @Joe how to the the old value in the `upsert` option. For example `value = preValue + newValue`

Comment: The `$inc` operator does that

Comment: @Joe can you make it an anser.